# A function from another helper file returning None instead of True. But the same function return True if put in same file from where I am calling it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not able to understand what is different when I put the below function in another file say - `abc.xyz.setup.setup_profiles`

```
def create_profile(profile_name, profile_value, matches):
rc_file_data = '''
           {some data here

       }
   '''
json_data = json.loads(rc_file_data)
'''
do something with jason data
'''
rc_file_path = "some-path"

with open(rc_file_path, 'w') as rcfile:
    json.dump(json_data, rcfile, indent=2)
    return True
return False
```

and call it as below -

```
from abc.xyz.setup.setup_profiles import create_profile

def anyfunc():
    print create_profile("something", "somevalue", "somevalue2")

anyfunc()
```

it returns None.

But if I put same create_profile function above function - anyfunc() in same file, it returns True.

Location of file containing function - anyfunc() is `abc.xyz.template.T111.`

I need to put these functions into two different files.
Help me understand whats wrong here.

Comment: are these files in the same folder ? if not, then the current running environment becomes the second file, when you run the second file,and python enviornment wont be able to pick up the file from the location, whereas, when you run your setup_profiles separately, that becomes the current environment. 
i would recommend mention the absolute path for the files, or add the folders to your sys environment path

Comment: Location of file containing function - anyfunc() is abc.xyz.template.T111

Comment: Can you guide me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you run setup_profiles directly it was able to read rc_file_path = "some-path" i.e. "some-path" was in the scope of the current running environment for python.

But when you run from another file the "some-path" i.e. rc_file_path wasn't in the scope for the python environment, so it wasnt able to read the file and returned None.

To have a quick fix, you can give the complete path

i.e.

```
rc_file_path = C:/...../somepath.txt
```

in windows.

or

```
rc_file_path = /home/username/..../somepath.txt
```

in linux

Or if you want to just pass the file name, in your current running environment, add the path/folder of the files to your environment using the following code.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"path to the directory of file/dependencies/config files which has to included")
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying.some path is already a complete path. like- /root/.nv/profilesfile.txt

Comment: did you try using sys.path.insert ? also make sure that path has write permissions.

Comment: I tried using sys.path.insert and yes it has write permissions. Everything else works in the create_profile function. Its just not returning True. I want to use it in IF statement.